# Terraform: Subnet in use azurerm

Tags: azure, networking, terraform

### Error Message

I get the following error message when executing `terraform apply`:

***Error: Error Creating/Updating Virtual Network "CTI-NETWORK" (Resource Group "CTI-RESOURCES"): network.VirtualNetworksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted" Message="Subnet CTI-PRD is in use by /subscriptions/d92e8f07-e127-4015-b67a-a547af76fdfc/resourceGroups/CTI-RESOURCES/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/CTI-NIC-PRD1/ipConfigurations/CTI-IP-PRD1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet." Details=[]***

I assume I've got a dependency mixed up but cant seem to figure it out.

### Code Snippet

Content of main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version         = "=1.38.0"
    subscription_id = "d92e8f07-e127-4015-b67a-a547af76fdfc"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
    name            = "${var.prefix}RESOURCES"
    location        = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "network" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}NETWORK"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "prd-subnet" {
    name                 = "${var.prefix}PRD"
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.network.name
    address_prefix       = "10.0.0.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "tst-subnet" {
    name                 = "${var.prefix}TST"
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.network.name
    address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ip-prd-1" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}PIP-PRD1"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    location            = var.location
    allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
    domain_name_label   = "vm-prd-1"
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-prd-1" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}NIC-PRD1"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    location            = var.location

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "${var.prefix}IP-PRD1"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.prd-subnet.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ip-prd-1.id
    }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-prd-1" {
    name                  = "${var.prefix}VM-PRD-1"
    location              = var.location
    resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic-prd-1.id]
    vm_size               = var.size

    delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
    delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher         = "credativ"
        offer             = "Debian"
        sku               = "9-backports"
        version           = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "lin-disk-1"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "${var.prefix}IP-PRD1"
        admin_username = "ADM-ADV"
        admin_password = "!!W0rksh0p"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
        application = "CTI Core"
    }
}








resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ip-prd-2" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}PIP-PRD-2"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    location            = var.location
    allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
    domain_name_label   = "vm-prd-2"
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-prd-2" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}NIC-PRD-2"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    location            = var.location

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "${var.prefix}IP-PRD-2"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.prd-subnet.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ip-prd-2.id
    }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-prd-chef" {
    name                  = "${var.prefix}VM-PRD-CHEF"
    location              = var.location
    resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic-prd-2.id]
    vm_size               = var.size

    delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
    delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher         = "Canonical"
        offer             = "UbuntuServer"
        sku               = "18.04-LTS"
        version           = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "lin-disk-2"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "${var.prefix}IP-PRD-CHEF"
        admin_username = "XXX"
        admin_password = "XXX"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
        application = "CTI Service"
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "touch /root/test.txt"
        ]
    }

}
```

Content of variables.tf

```
variable "prefix" {
    type            = string
    default         = "CTI-"
    description     = "Prefix of the resources"
}

variable "location" {
    type            = string
    default         = "westeurope"
    description     = "Location of the resources"
}

variable "size" {
    type            = string
    default         = "Standard_A1_v2"
    description     = "Size of the virtual machines"
}
```

> Thanks for you help!

Comment: Do you update the existing Vnet or create the new Vnet?

Comment: Compared to current state I'm adding new VM, the VM has nic in one of the subnets

Comment: Use the existing subnet or create a new one? I see you're going to create a new Vnet and subnet.

Comment: I create the nic using `azurerm_subnet.prd-subnet.id` in an already existing subnet (at least that is what I'm trying to do)

Comment: What is the situation now? I didn't see any response. Do you still want to solve the problem?

Comment: Why not accept the answer while it seems to solve your problem? If not, why not give responses? Or you only come to get the answer and do not want to accept it?!

Answer (score 0):

With the message you provided, you want to create another VM in the existing subnet of the Vnet. So you need to use the data resource instead of the resource format. Change your Terraform code like this:

Change:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "network" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}NETWORK"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "prd-subnet" {
    name                 = "${var.prefix}PRD"
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.network.name
    address_prefix       = "10.0.0.0/24"
}
```

Into:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "network" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}NETWORK"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "prd-subnet" {
    name = "${var.prefix}PRD"
    virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.network.name
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-prd-1" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}NIC-PRD1"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
    location            = var.location

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "${var.prefix}IP-PRD1"
        subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.prd-subnet.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ip-prd-1.id
    }
}
```

The Terraform data will quote the existing resource and do not change them. If the other subnet `tst-subnet` is also existing, you can change it like above yourself.